# Can't install Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 32-bit

I am trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox and after I create a VM, I set a 32-bit Ubuntu iso file as a disk and it boots normally. After that I click "Install Ubuntu" but an error message is displayed as below in the pic. The problem isn't because of a discrepancy in computer architecture because I tried the 64-bit version but that didn't solve the case. Any help would be welcomed.

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: Does VirtualBox work at all with any other guests? The error you get indicates that this is a problem with virtualbox and/or your host OS, *not* Ubuntu.

Comment: The error indicates that Virtual Box crashed **on the host**. It may help to  upgrade VBox to the latest release, or to assign fewer resources to the guest (i.e. less RAM, less CPU cores).

Comment: I have 2gb of RAM and a dual core CPU. I assigned 1gb of RAM to the guest and a single core.

Comment: @takkat I tried 512mb of RAM and it didnt solve the problem. I even tried 256mb and it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify for anyone who crashes into the same problem as I did. It seems that my PC couldnt run the latest Ubuntu(maybe because my PC doesnt have enough RAM to be able to hold it). I tried installing an old version of Ubuntu and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the requirements for running Windows 10.  It seems like it can't do what you are asking it to do.  For example, Windows 10 64bit requires 2GB or ram.  Since that is all you have, you can't give 1GB to Virtualbox.

Comment: I have a windows 10 32bit that requires 1gb Ram to run properly, so it means that if I use the other gb or less for the guest it shouldnt cause the machine to crash.