# Installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and wants a VM with another install of Ubuntu to try out some stuff.

I've installed VirtualBox as describes on their website (added ppa) and followed [this post](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-virtualbox) on how to install it.

When I try to boot it up I get a popup saying the following:

[image: Error message]

So... I've tried to search the forum, but [like this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019123/cant-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) they doesn't describe their problem in detail and the last post doesnt seem to be my problem. I have 16 GB of ram.

However when I look into the logs I see that there's a problem reading the ISO and the VM Disk:

```
00:00:00.794924 VirtualBox VM 6.1.18 r142142 linux.amd64 (Jan  7 2021 17:36:17) release log
00:00:00.794926 Log opened 2021-02-27T10:46:27.374821000Z
00:00:00.794926 Build Type: release
00:00:00.794929 OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.794930 OS Release: 5.8.0-44-generic
00:00:00.794931 OS Version: #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021
00:00:00.794947 DMI Product Name: 20KFCTO1WW
00:00:00.794952 DMI Product Version: ThinkPad X280
00:00:00.794957 Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:00.795549 Secure Boot: Enabled
00:00:00.795583 Host RAM: 15760MB (15.3GB) total, 10827MB (10.5GB) available
00:00:00.795586 Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM
00:00:00.795586 Process ID: 27519
00:00:00.795587 Package type: LINUX_64BITS_UBUNTU_19_10
00:00:00.806297 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:00.806323   None installed!
00:00:00.807016 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:00.807171 Qt version: 5.12.8
00:00:00.807192 X11 Window Manager code: 2
00:00:00.810712 SUP: seg #0: R   0x00000000 LB 0x0004c000
00:00:00.810778 SUP: seg #1: R X 0x0004c000 LB 0x00114000
00:00:00.810823 SUP: seg #2: R   0x00160000 LB 0x0005f000
00:00:00.810831 SUP: seg #3: RW  0x001bf000 LB 0x00035060
00:00:00.812782 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (/usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:00.812819 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and VMMR0EntryFast at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:00.814081 Guest OS type: 'Ubuntu_64'
00:00:00.815672 fHMForced=true - No raw-mode support in this build!
00:00:00.819263 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:00.820811 X Server details: vendor: The X.Org Foundation, release: 12009000, protocol version: 11.0, display string: :0
00:00:00.820842 Using XKB for keycode to scan code conversion
00:00:00.821575 File system of '/home/joachim/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso' (DVD) is unknown
00:00:00.823308 GUI: UIDesktopWidgetWatchdog::sltHandleHostScreenAvailableGeometryCalculated: Screen 0 work area is actually resized to: 48x27 x 1872x1053
00:00:00.826613 File system of '/home/joachim/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu Eoan/Snapshots' (snapshots) is unknown
00:00:00.826651 File system of '/home/joachim/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu Eoan/Ubuntu Eoan.vdi' is unknown
00:00:00.838188 Shared Clipboard: Service loaded
00:00:00.838223 Shared Clipboard: Mode: Off
00:00:00.838267 Shared Clipboard: Service running in normal mode
00:00:00.838949 Drag and drop service loaded
00:00:00.838972 Drag and drop mode: Off
00:00:00.840708 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
```

Lines like these:

```
00:00:00.826651 File system of '/home/joachim/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu Eoan/Ubuntu Eoan.vdi' is unknown
```

I've tried to install the extension pack without any luck.

My host system uses ZFS. Could this be related?

Anyone else experienced this and maybe solved it somehow?

Comment: Read somewhere that a dynamic VDI could be problematic with ZFS and tried fixed size without any difference.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out to be a GUI issue. Found a line containing the following in the logs

```
Argument aWidth is invalid (must be aWidth != 0 && aWidth <= 32767)
```

And then ran

```
vboxmanage setextradata "Eoan" "GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition"
```

in the terminal (Eoan is the name of the VM instance), re-opened VirtualBox and everything booted smoothly.